# How to update October CMS. Without data loss

Tags: php, laravel, octobercms

Good day to all. I have a website on October CMS , it has been working for a year. The client received a letter that they need to update October CMS. If anyone knows, please help, how can I update the October CMS WITHOUT DATA LOSS. Thank you in advance.
Below.
Screenshots Dashboard and Plugins list.
[image: Dashboard]

[image: Plugins List]

Comment: just press `check update` button if you see everything green for each plugin dropbox. click update all will be updated without data loos. NOTE : make sure to do this first on local environment then do it on live

Comment: Yes, I checked. But is this just updating the plugins? Or isn’t it? I need to upgrade a complete system.

Comment: It will also update core part as well means whole system :) so do not worry . again sorry for annoying but NOTE: try on local first :)